# Is there a simpler way to automate expanding PVC volume for a statefulset in K8 version 1.24 using manifest?

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine

I am stuck at an issue and would appreciate your inputs/suggestions.

Requirement: Expand pvc volume of a statefulset dynamically through manifest.
K8 version 1.24
Using GKE

I know since 1.24 K8 allow dynamic pvc expansion with kubectl patch command but thats not something i want.

current operation:

expand volume by kubectl patch -> raise a pull request on github -> merge -> delete sts with cascade orphan option.

This basically brings back the Argo cd in sync state.

I have to automate this manual process of expanding pvc by changing it in the statefulset manifest and deleting the statefulset with cascade orphan option. Since I want a reference of the increased volume in the manifest file.

My thoughts:

so far, I have explored multiple options including employing Argo CD and Argo workflow along with Google cloud native components cloudrun, pubsub etc. All this seems like a bit of a stretch for implementing a simple solution.

Problems with employing cloud run:

-> Authentication requirements at multiple places.
-> If i implement a github webhook to trigger a cloud run on merge. There will be a lot of triggering and i would need to implement a business logic in the cloud run to cater to a particular merge.

Problems with Argo workflow:

-> My idea rn is to raise a pull request, store the PR number and keep the workflow in suspended/wait state until i receive a success response for PR merge from Github API.
-> Problems comes if the PR is not merged for several days i would have a workflow pending all this time.

This all feels like a too much implementation for a simple problem. I am wondering if someone in the community have face this issue and might have a better idea for a simple implementation?

Since this is my first question in the community i would really appreciate your inputs if this is not the best way to ask a question and where i can improve.

Thanks in advance!